# Install and configure mysql using ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible

I have installed MySql, nginx and PHP using the below ansible-playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Make Sure we can connect to hosts
      ping:
    - name: Install PHP
      yum: name={{item}} state=present update_cache=yes
      with_items:
        - php
        - php-fpm
        - php-mysql
        - php-xml
    - name: add repository nginx-release (CentOS6/CentOS7)
      yum: name="http://nginx.org/packages/centos/{{ansible_distribution_major_version}}/noarch/RPMS/nginx-release-centos-{{ansible_distribution_major_version}}-0.el{{ansible_distribution_major_version}}.ngx.noarch.rpm"
    - name: Install nginx
      yum: name=nginx state=installed enablerepo=nginx
    - name: Download MySQL Community Repo
      command: /usr/bin/rpm -ivh /tmp/mysql-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
    - name: Install MySql
      yum: name={{item}} state=installed
      with_items:
        - mysql-server
        - MySQL-python
```

I am trying to configure mysql using ansible using the below ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: ansible-ctl
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Make Sure we can connect to hosts
      ping:
    - name: Start MySQL Server and enable it
      service: name=mysqld state=started enabled=yes
    - name: Generate new root password
      command: openssl rand -hex 7 creates=/root/.my.cnf
      register: mysql_new_root_pass
    - name: Create my.cnf
      template: src=templates/mysql/my.cnf dest=/root/.my.cnf
      when: mysql_new_root_pass.changed
    - name: Remove anonymous users
      mysql_user: name='' host_all=yes state=absent
      when: mysql_new_root_pass.changed
    - name: Remove test database
      mysql_db: name=test state=absent
      when: mysql_new_root_pass.changed
    - name: Output new root password
      debug: msg="New root password is {{mysql_new_root_pass.stdout}}"
      when: mysql_new_root_pass.changed
    - name: Update root password
      mysql_user: name=root host={{item}} password={{mysql_new_root_pass.stdout}}
      with_items:
        - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
        - 127.0.0.1
        - ::1
        - localhost
      when: mysql_new_root_pass.changed
```

The my.cnf template file resides in /templates/mysql/ location :

```
[client]
user=root
password={{ mysql_new_root_pass.stdout }}
```

The file `/root/.my.cnf` file is generating with a password.

First I am starting mysql service. Then using openssl creating a new password and storing it in `mysql_new_root_pass`. Then based on existence of `/root/.my.cnf` file I am trying to perform tasks like removing anonymous users, removing test database and updating the root password. But my playbook is throwing error at the step `Remove Anonymous Users`. Below is the error I receive:

```
fatal: [ansible-ctl]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1045, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)\")"}
```

I am following the book from Apress - Ansible Beginner to Pro and also the following link [Installing MySQL on Centos 7 server using Ansible](http://www.wiivil.com/installing-mysql-on-centos-7-server-using-ansible/). My ansible controller is a Macbook Pro with Centos 7 Minimal running on a VM.

The generated .my.cnf :

```js
[client]
user=root
password=<generated password>
```

Could anybody explain what is going wrong here and how could I remove the anonymous users?

Comment: publish the template used pushed to `/root/.my.cnf` (replace sensitive information)

Answer (score 0):

This fails because as soon you create the file `/root/.my.cnf` it will be used to connect to mysql but you did not have yet updated the root user's password.
Move the task `name: Update root password` just before the task `name: Create my.cnf`

Comment: Hi @baptistemm now I am getting the same error in the update password task `
failed: [ansible-ctl] (item=localhost) => {"changed": false, "item": "localhost", "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1045, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)\")"}`